# FireDAC Image BLOB as FDStoredProc parameter

Tags: delphi, blob, delphi-xe, firedac, insert-image

I Have problem with inserting images to database via FireDAC stored procedure.

I trying use memory stream

```
ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;
ms.Position:=0;
image1.Bitmap.SaveToStream(ms);
ms.Position:=0

FDStoredProc1.ParamByName('@img').LoadFromStream(ms,ftBlob);
```

but this ends with an `AccessViolation`.

Then I try direct load image from path

```
FDStoredProc1.ParamByName('@img').LoadFromFile('C:\f\1.jpg',ftBlob);
```

but this ends with an error message "Stream read error" !

Can anybody help me ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Let me know if the dupe fixes your problem. If not I'll reopen.

Comment: I have seen this post, but it is not solution for my problem ? and If why I must clear all parameters and create they manualy in code ?

Comment: You don't have to, you can create them in the object inspector.

Comment: but I have created all parameters automaticaly ! .... If parameters are not image type this SP works fine.
What is different If I delete all parameters and create it manually in object inspector or code ?

Comment: That's exactly what the dupe is about.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, @Johan. Parameters are created, parameter found (?, that @ char in parameter name smells) and data type hinted, maybe badly.